# $\lim \frac{x}{\sin x} = +\infty$ or $-\infty $ as $ x \rightarrow (n\pi) , n \neq 0$ is a wrong statement.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, analysis

$$\lim \frac{x}{\sin x} = +\infty \textrm{ or } -\infty $$ as   $ x \rightarrow (n\pi) , n \neq 0$ is a wrong statement. My professor told me this and he told me that the correct statement to write is:

$$\lim \frac{x}{\sin x} = +\infty \textrm{ or } -\infty $$ as   $ x \rightarrow (n\pi)^+ , n \neq 0$

But I do not understand how this "+" above the $(n \pi)$ yields to  $ +\infty$ or $-\infty $, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Do you miss anything in your limit expression? You mentioned $x\to(n\pi)+$ but there is no $x$ in your limit.

Comment: Sorry I have corrected it @user587192

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that for $n\neq 0$

$$\lim_{x\to n\pi^+} \frac{x}{\sin x}$$

doesn't exist since it leads to a different limit for n even or odd.

Indeed let consider for example

- $x\to \pi^+ \implies \sin x \to 0^- \implies \lim_{x\to \pi^+} \frac{x}{\sin x}=-\infty$

but for

- $x\to 2\pi^+ \implies \sin x \to 0^+\implies \lim_{x\to 2\pi^+} \frac{x}{\sin x}=+\infty$.

Comment: I want an explanation for what my professor said. if $n=0$ the limit is 1

Comment: why the last limit lead to different limit ..... this is what I am asking ..... for n even it is what and for n odd it is what?

Comment: @hopefully For n=0 the expression in not defined since we obtain $0/0$.

Comment: @hopefully Let consider for example that for $$x\to \pi^+ \implies \sin x \to 0^-$$ but for $$x\to 2\pi^+ \implies \sin x \to 0^+$$.

Comment: Why as $x \rightarrow \pi ^+$ we have that $\sin x \rightarrow 0^-$ could you explain this please?

Comment: @hopefully Just consider the graph for $\sin x$ which is negative for $x\in(\pi,3\pi/2)$ or the trigonometric circle.

Comment: okay thank you :)

Comment: @hopefully You are welcome! Bye